# How do I export pandas processed data to excel and want to add a row to the top of the data?

Tags: python, pandas

This is how the DataFrame would look like:

```
            Product  Price
0  Desktop Computer   1200
1           Printer    150
2            Tablet    300
3           Monitor    450
```

When I export this data to excel, I want to add a row to the top of the excel and the completed addition will look like this：

[image]

I would like to add a row at the top of the excel: Purchase items and prices.
Can you tell me how to achieve this?